# How many replicas for express (NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, autoscaling, replicaset

So before I used kubernetes the general rule I used for running multiple express instances on a VM was one per cpu. That seemed to give the best performance.
For kubernetes, would it be wise to have a replica per node cpu? Or should I let the horizontalpodautoscaler decide? The cluster has a node autoscaler.
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good question !

You need to consider 4 things :

1. Run the pod using **Deployment** so you enable replication, rolling update,...so on
2. Set `resources.limits` to your container definition. this is mandatory for autoscaling , because HPA is monitoring the percentage of usage, and if there is **NO limit**, there will be **NEVER percentage**, then HPA will never reach the **threshold**.
3. Set `resources.requests`. This will help the scheduler to estimate how much the app needs, so it will be assigned to the suitable Node per its current capacity.
4. Set HPA threshold: The  percentage of usage (CPU, memory)  when the HPA will trigger scale out or scale in.

for your situation, you said "one per cpu".. then, it should be:

```
  containers:
  - name: express
    image: myapp-node
    #.....
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "750m"
      limits:
        memory: "512Mi"
        cpu: "1000m" # <--  match what you have in the legacy deployment
```

you may wonder why I put memory limits/requests without any input from your side ?
The answer is that I put it randomly. Your task is to monitor your application, and adjust all these values accordingly.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks! So I guess my remaining question comes down to the HPA, I could set the minReplicas to 1, but for the max would I not want to exceed the number of CPUs of a Node? At least it still sounds like that is best if I am seeing that performance benefit from the legacy infrastructure.

Comment: Also (sorry), for a cluster that is going to be solely running this Express app, would it even make sense to have an HPA, and instead just run at max replicas and resources per node (and let the node autoscaler scale the cluster)? Thanks.

Comment: Oh and last thing, by HPA threshold do you mean the "behavior"?

Comment: Depends on your load ! HPA is getting mature by time. Try it ! if you don't like its behavior, wait for the stable release of HPA. Otherwise, we are using HPA and we are happy. Put in mind that many things come together even the initDelayinSeconds on LivenessProbe and others.

Comment: HPA **threshold** depends on the **apiVersion of HPA**. For example, threshold in HPA apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2 is mapped to `metrics[*].type.target.averageUtilization` . For old apiVersion, it is mapped to `targetCPUUtilizationPercentage` ... depends on your apiVersion of HPA.

Comment: Yeah I think for an API (at least this one) it would be best to keep the pods consuming max node resources and let the node autoscaler work to scale the cluster up and down as needed.

Comment: container limits are must in production workload. Because the Node does not have only your apps... **a node does not come empty** !!! it must run core apps like kubelet, kube-proxy, container-runtime(docker) and finally other daemonset.. If you give freedom to your app consume resources, your app might throttle/or might be throttled by these core apps. Think about Cluster.. Not individual Node... Forget about traditional VMs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217669/discussion-between-danthegoodman-and-abdennour-toumi).

Comment: Do you prefer HPA scaling based on deployment or replicaset?

Comment: Just a correction: HPA calculated utilisation in relation to resources.requests and NOT resources.limits! see https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details